# setting sizing_mode bokeh property for holowviews generated plot

Tags: bokeh, dashboard, holoviews

I'm having some sizing issue(responsiveness) with holoviews chart rendered with bokeh in a custom template.

Could anyone help figure out how to give properties like plot_height=200 & sizing_mode="scale_width" to Bokeh plot returned by Holoviews?

I tried giving to holoview generated bokeh chart

```
myb.plot_height = 200
myb.sizing_mode="scale_width"
```

tried this as well on hv

```
boxwhisker.options(show_legend=False, height=200, sizing_mode='scale_width')
```

But it's not taking above properties into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Got an update from holoviews team [here](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/3062). Looking forward for the fix.